# Binding element 'input' implicitly has an 'any' type in redux form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form

I am new to React with Typescript i am trying to create a redux form component.But when it is compiled i am getting the error as below

[image]

I have tried to add props as below but i don't know whether the approach is correct or not.

```
interface FormInputProps {
  input: any,
  iconName: string,
  placeHolder: string,
  inputType: string,
  meta: object,
}
```

```
const FormInput = ({
  input,
  iconName,
  placeHolder,
  inputType,
  meta: { error, touched }
}) => (
  <FormGroup>
    <InputGroup className="mb-3">
      <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
        <InputGroupText>
          <i className={iconName}/>
        </InputGroupText>
      </InputGroupAddon>
      <Input
        {...input}
        type={inputType}
        placeholder={placeHolder} />
    </InputGroup>
    {touched && <FormText className="help-block error-color">{error}</FormText>}
  </FormGroup>
);
```

Comment: the typings for redux-form exists in `InjectedFormProps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: 
Tried like below and it works fine

```
  const FormInput = (field: any) => (
  <FormGroup>
    <InputGroup className="mb-3">
      <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
        <InputGroupText>
          <i className={field.iconName}/>
        </InputGroupText>
      </InputGroupAddon>
      <Input
        {...field.input}
        type={field.inputType}
        placeholder={field.placeHolder} />
    </InputGroup>
    {field.touched && <FormText className="help-block error-color">{field.error}</FormText>}
  </FormGroup>
);

export default FormInput;
```

Comment: This is not the answer, this is not the way you use Typescript if you want to define everything as `any` then why bothering yourself using Typescript?

Answer (score 1):

```
import {InjectedFormProps} from 'redux-form';
interface FormInputProps {/*other local thing*/} extends InjectedFormProps;

const FormInput:React.FC<FormInputProps> = ()=>{...}
```

Comment: what we will do in other local thing

Comment: other props which are not part of `InjectedFormProps` by `Ctrl+click` you can go to `.d.ts` file and see all the props and typing declared

Comment: So do we need to tell the prop type

Comment: I do not know, I have never worked with Redux-Form, but in general, for typescript, most libraries come with their type declarations or can be installed via `@types/module name`  if the props, (input, iconName, placeholder,...) are part of redux-form so no need to redefine them cause your props interface is extending.